# How to get media attribute from SDP body in pjsua2?

Tags: sip, voip, pjsip, sdp, pjsua2

Is there any way to get the media attribute, which is part of the SDP body, from a callback function or similar with the PJSUA2-library?

I'm looking for a way to get the remote media port and IP address that were sent in a SIP INVITE request.

I know how to register a callback for incoming calls, however, afaik, that callback does not include any information about the remote party.

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse there is a way to do this. For example in `on_call_media_state` callback:

1. include pjsua_internal header file: `#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua_internal.h>`
2. get `pjsua_call` structure pointer using call_id from callback's argument: `pjsua_call *call = &pjsua_var.calls[call_id];`
3. now you're able to read current local and remote SDP:

   ```
   const pjmedia_sdp_session *remote_sdp;
   const pjmedia_sdp_session *local_sdp;
   pj_status_t status = pjmedia_sdp_neg_get_active_remote(call->inv->neg, &remote_sdp);
   pj_status_t status = pjmedia_sdp_neg_get_active_local(call->inv->neg, &local_sdp);
   for (int i = 0; i < remote_sdp->media_count; i++) {
       // structure with access to SDP m values
       pjmedia_sdp_media *m = remote_sdp->media[i];
   }
   ```

I didn't run this code, but it should work.

Hope that will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Excellent advice by DaszuOne!
Here is the complete working snippet copying SDP address:port for all media, comma separated if more than one (requires #include <pjmedia/sdp_neg.h> to get SDP negotiation state)

```
void MyCall::onCallState(OnCallStateParam &prm) {
    CallInfo ci = getInfo();
    pjsua_call *call = &pjsua_var.calls[ci.id];

    if(call->inv->neg && pjmedia_sdp_neg_get_state(call->inv->neg) == PJMEDIA_SDP_NEG_STATE_DONE){
        string remote_addr="";
        const pjmedia_sdp_session *remote_sdp;
        if(PJ_SUCCESS==pjmedia_sdp_neg_get_active_remote(call->inv->neg, &remote_sdp)){
            for (int i = 0; i < remote_sdp->media_count; i++) {
                if(i>0)
                    remote_addr.append(",");
                pjmedia_sdp_media *m = remote_sdp->media[i];
                remote_addr.append(string(m->conn->addr.ptr,m->conn->addr.slen));
                remote_addr.append(":");
                remote_addr.append(to_string(m->desc.port));
            }
        }else{
            remote_addr="<none>";
        }
        callstate->othermedia = remote_addr;

        string local_addr="";
        const pjmedia_sdp_session *local_sdp;
        if(PJ_SUCCESS==pjmedia_sdp_neg_get_active_local(call->inv->neg, &local_sdp)){
            for (int i = 0; i < local_sdp->media_count; i++) {
                if(i>0)
                    local_addr.append(",");
                pjmedia_sdp_media *m = local_sdp->media[i];
                local_addr.append(string(m->conn->addr.ptr,m->conn->addr.slen));
                local_addr.append(":");
                local_addr.append(to_string(m->desc.port));
            }
        }else{
            local_addr="<none>";
        }
        callstate->mymedia = local_addr;
    }

    callstate->stateText = ci.stateText;
    callstate->update();
};
```